# shared parameters between plugins

Tags: gazebo-1.9, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody I am writing a simulation that involves multiple plugins. Some time I need to pass data between the plugins, for example images or the positions. The thing is that all the plugins write on different ROS topics and I want them to robustly read/write the same topics.
By "robustly" I mean that the topics are user-defined in the sdf description of the model. I would like to define some shared fields so that a topic name is used in multiple plugins without inserting the same name in all the plugin definition, is it possible?
I hope I have been clear
Thanks
Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5531/shared-parameters-between-plugins/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

for ROS i would recomment using URDF and xacro.
In xacro you can do exactly what you are asking for. xacro also has the possibility to hand over arguments for the configuration. This way you could change the definition  for usage with multiple robot instances without modifing the config file...

if you want to use SDF and self written plugins you could think about using the parameter server to store this information...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2014-02-28**:
I think I will opt for a parameter server.  Thank  you very much!